# Beamer different Framesubtitles

Tags: beamer

How do I add different subtitles in the same frame,like in frame literature review I add subtitle 2.1 introduction, subtitle 2.2  development etc

Comment: Do you want different framesubtitles showing after each other as overlays or do you want several framesubtitles in one frame at the same time? Please clarify further what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yes please ,I want different framesubtitles showing after each other

Answer (score 3):

`\framesubtitle` is an overlay-aware command, so you can simply specify for which slide the subtitle should be used:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{literature review}
\framesubtitle<1>{introduction}
\framesubtitle<2>{development}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an overlay command like `\only` you can show different framesubtitles in one frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{literature review}
\only<1>{\framesubtitle{introduction}}
\only<2>{\framesubtitle{development}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```